# Forward HTTP requests with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, forwarding

Is there some way to forward with Rails any incoming HTTP request to other web site as is, regardless of request type and its data?

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, you can collect a request headers, payload and details, and perform an HTTP request to another target reproducing the same request environment (cookies, headers, etc) effectively proxying the request... but I definitely think Rails is not the best solution for that.

You should definitely use a different approach and technology, for instance HAproxy or Nginx.